# Bootstrap Dashboard Example in Asp.Net

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some issues with implementing bootstrap in my asp page. How do I get the ContentPlaceHolder of my asp master page to the right of my Navbar?

Master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Main.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Main" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/#">Project name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/#">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/#">Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/#">Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/#">Help</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
                <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                    <li class="active"><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/#">Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/#">Reports</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/#">Analytics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/#">Export</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                    <li><a href="">Nav item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">More navigation</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="Container">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This puts the content under the navigation bar, which will look like this:

[image]

I need to know where to implement ContentPlaceHolder.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `<div class="Container">` into the above `<div class="container-fluid">`

Remove also the `col-sm-offset-X` from the `ContentPlaceHolder1` if needed.

Here is a working **[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/DBrA8hXXqH)**

Comment: This puts my sidebar on the right side of my content instead of on the left where it belongs?